# Laravel Livewire Save to Collection and Show in Component View

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I am using Laravel Livewire to choose an item from a dropdown list (which passes an ID), I then find the Model that ID belongs to and I want to add that Model to a collection. Then each additional time I choose something from the dropdown list I want to update the existing collection with that new Model.

```
public $workoutExercises;

public function mount()
{
  $this->workoutExercises = collect([]);
}

public function submitExercise()
{
  $newExercise = Exercise::where('id', $this->exercise)->first();

  $this->workoutExercises->push($newExercise);

  return;
}
```

In the component view:

```
@foreach ($workoutExercises as $workoutExercise)
  {{ $workoutExercise->exercise_name }}
@endforeach
```

When I submit a new exercise it adds it to the collection and shows up in my view as intended. However, when I go to add an ADDITIONAL exercise I get this error..."Attempt to read property "exercise_name" on array".

I don't get it. It's like it adds the first one fine, but resorts to an array instead of a collection for any subsequent submissions?

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

Behind the back, Livewire uses all the things like an array, so when the component first loads your `$workoutExercises` is a collection, but after the first request it turns into an array. What I usually do is create an array of id's selected and query the data as a computed property.

```php
public array $workoutExerciseIds = [];

public function submitExercise(): void
{
  array_push($workoutExerciseIds, $this->exercise);
}

public function getWorkoutExecisesProperty()
{
    return Exercise::query()
        ->whereIn('id', $this->workoutExerciseIds)
        ->get();
}
```

Then on my front end:

```php
@foreach ($this->workoutExercises as $workoutExercise)
  {{ $workoutExercise->exercise_name }}
@endforeach
```